# Can't display name on html page from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I am creating a login and play. I have all the code working for the login and connecting to the database and playing the game. But I cant get the user name to be posted on the play page. This is the code that I have included in the play java file.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LottoDB", "root", "root");

        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Users where userName = ?");

        String user = request.getParameter("user_name");
        st.setString(1, user);
        ResultSet r1 = st.executeQuery();
        while (r1.next()) {

            out.println("<br><P> Hello ! </P>"+ user);


        }
```

Comment: Your parameter doesn't match the column in the DB, is that intended?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you have not mention the *column index* or *column name* of the username when getting the result from *resultset*, you must say something like this:

```
 while (r1.next()) {
        out.println("<br><P> Hello ! </P>"+ r1getString(1));
        // or out.println("<br><P> Hello ! </P>"+ r1getString("username"));
    }
```

Comment: what error does it gives? have you put the correct column name there?

Comment: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it to work. I get a null back. I think its because im taking the value from the login html and its connected to a different servlet.

Comment: you are welcome, maybe tracing that piece of code and seeing the parameter and the query result help you, anyway, I hope you'll get it fixed soon. good luck.

Comment: Do you know how I can access the username value in the login servlet and then have it displayed on the play servlet page ? Please any help ??